# Authorize.net can we use 1 card for 2 different customer payment profiles?

Tags: authorize.net

I am using authorize.net and everything works fine, now I have a scenario where I need to create multiple `Customer Payment Profiles` using 1 card. I want to know is that even possible or we need to have separate card for each customer payment profile? for recurring payments

TIA

I am exploring docs and not sure if thats possible or not

Comment: You can try it out yourself using their test API

Comment: I think you should be able to, here is the docs that explain what may be considered as duplicate profiles. Ref.: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/customer-profiles.html